# Cómo pongo campo de texto para números y letras

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo el software para un parqueadero, pero necesito que ésta celda me permita guardar la placa del vehículo (carro/moto) y que sean sólo caracteres de letras y números, que no acepte valores distintos.

```html
<tr>
    <!-- Caja de texto para la placa -->
    <td id="TituloTablaVerde">
        <b><i>Placa:</i>
    </td>

    <td>
        <input type="text" name="placa" required minlength="6" maxlength="10" placeholder="Placa" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Otra cosa y es que necesito que el campo quede sólo para letras mayúsculas, en la parte de `onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();` me las cambia en tiempo real, osea que si empieza a escribir en minúsculas, el campo empieza a convertirla en mayúsculas (la idea es que lo convierta sin mostrar el proceso.

Comment: Puedes usar el attributo `pattern`, como `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"`

Comment: No me sirvió, ya lo puse y nada pasó.-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta solución tiene dos partes: por un lado, la estética, para que los caracteres aparezcan en mayúsculas aunque se escriban en minúsculas. Pero a la vez se transforman realmente a mayúsculas y no permite escribir nada que no sea letras del alfabeto latino estándar (sin acentos ni ñ) o números. Sí que se ve cómo se borran los caracteres no válidos, pero no encuentro ninguna solución a esa parte.

```js
function filterNonAphaNumeric(str) {
  let code, i, len,result='';

  for (i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    code = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if ((code > 47 && code < 58) || // numeric (0-9)
        (code > 64 && code < 91) || // upper alpha (A-Z)
        (code > 96 && code < 123)) { // lower alpha (a-z)
      result+=str.charAt(i);
    }
  }
  return result;
};

function onKeyUpHandler(event) {
  let value=this.value.toUpperCase();
  if (value) {
    this.value=filterNonAphaNumeric(value)
  }
}

let input = document.getElementById('placa');
input.addEventListener('keyup',onKeyUpHandler);
```

```css
.uppercase {
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <!-- Caja de texto para la placa -->
  <td id="TituloTablaVerde"><b><i>Placa:</i></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="placa" id="placa" required minlength="6" maxlength="10" placeholder="Placa" class="uppercase"></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Traga caracteres especiales si los mantiene pulsados. No me habia dado por probar nunca, ¿sera cosa del navegador? ¿Si es asi se podrian sustitur con el onchange? Aunque soy mas partidario de tratar los datos desde atras.

Comment: @GDP bien visto, arreglaré eso

Answer (score 0):

## Prueba lo siguiente:

```
<textarea id="ta" name="textarea" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>

<script>
document.getElementById("ta").addEventListener("keypress",verificar);
function verificar(e) {
    if(e.key.match(/[a-z0-9ñçáéíóú\s]/i)===null) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, es importante comentar que es lo que realiza el código y de que forma ayudaría a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, revisa [answer], saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Para validar los campos de texto o campos numéricos, los navegadores nos ofrecen opciones pero no son tan estrictas y no sirven para todos. A través de Javascript se puede realizar tareas de procesamientos de texto y caracteres introducidos en un formulario.

Primero creamos la función en javascript.

```
function validaPlaca(e) {
key = e.keyCode || e.which; 
tecla = String.fromCharCode(key).toString();
 //Se define todo lo que se quiere que se muestre
caracter = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
especiales = [8, 37, 39, 46, 6]; 

tecla_especial = false; 
for (var i in especiales) {
      if(key == especiales[i]) { 
    tecla_especial = true; 
     break; 
      }
} 
if(caracter.indexOf (tecla) == -1 && !tecla_especial){ 
    alert('Tecla no aceptada'); 
    return false; 
}
```

}

Para llamar la función en html.

```
> <label>Placa:</label> 
> <input id="Placa" name="Placa" required minlength="6" maxlength="10"   
> onkeypress="return validaPlaca(event);"  onKeyUp="this.value =
> this.value.toUpperCase();">
```

El `onKeyUp="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();` se utiliza para que todas las letras digitadas se vuelvan mayúsculas.

Comment: te has olvidado de las mayúsculas en tu variable `caracter` (aunque no sé por qué alguien ha votado negativo sin explicar nada)

Answer (score -2):

Aquí una opción con CSS. Espero te sirva.
Solo aclaro que cuando se hace con CSS no se convierten las letras, solo es estética por si quisieras por ejemplo insertar en tu base de datos, se insertarían minúsculas.

```css
input.mayusculas{text-transform:uppercase;
```

```html
<tr>
  <!-- Caja de texto para la placa -->
  <td id="TituloTablaVerde"><b><i>Placa:</i></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="placa" class="mayusculas" required minlength="6" maxlength="10" placeholder="Placa"></td>
    </tr>
```